# internal error (java.nio.file.invalidpathexception): Illegal char <?> at index 34

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

Trying simple junit tests....

```
public class ZZZZ {
    private int a;

    public ZZZZ() {
    }

    public int test(int a){

        return a/a;
    }
}
```

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class ZZZZTest1 {


    private int a = 1;

    ZZZZ nov = new ZZZZ();

    @Test
    public void testtt(){
        assertEquals(6, nov.test(a));
    }
}
```

and i get this... I have no idea what to do since I am not really experienced intellij java user

```
Internal error (java.nio.file.InvalidPathException): Illegal char <?> at index 34: D:/Fakultet/Programiranje Proekti/????, ??, ????/untitled
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 34: D:/Fakultet/Programiranje Proekti/????, ??, ????/untitled
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:87)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.impl.JpsSerializationManagerImpl.loadModel(JpsSerializationManagerImpl.java:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:34)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:279)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:132)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:219)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Any ideas on what I should do ?

Comment: In Windows settings go to "Region -> Administrative -> Change system locale -> Untick "Beta: Use Unicode..." option. Reboot. Does it help?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Unfortunately not... I already have the setting as mentioned on the comment - Beta: Use Unicode: unticked... 
For future reference I use AdoptJDK 11, if that's of any help... also I would like to note that I already did these tests successfully on another project, then I started a new one which required junit libs -> downloaded them, now both my projects get this error... I am completely clueless as of what I am supposed to do, maybe a JDK and Intellij reinstall? although I am not sure how that helps if the problem occurs again

Comment: Please add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restart IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Comment: Moving your project outside of the home directory which has non-ascii characters should help.

Comment: The other project gets No tests were found error... I have no characters left, otherwise I would've summarized the errors here....

Comment: YouTrack or support would be the best channel to solve this kind of issues.

Comment: Moving your project outside of the home directory which has non-ascii characters should help - this one helped... my tests are fine now ._.  

Really appreciate you time <3 
If I have related issues I will make sure you use YT

Answer (score 0):

@CrazyCoder

Moving your project outside of the home directory which has non-ascii characters should help. –

Not sure how to give rep this is the best I can do I think

Answer (score 0):

When i got this error  (mine was  `Illegal char <:>`) i ve found in `values` folder whole commented inside `attrs.xml` file and removed it. Now it compiles ok